# Chrome app and connecting to google doc

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-chrome-app

I want to start looking at using chrome apps as a possible IT solution.  I used this tutorial to create a quick app:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab_basics

My next step is to connect to an external data source, where multiple users could access (read/write) to the same source.  Is it possible to read/write to the following, and if so, are there any tutorials:

1. Google Sheet, stored on google drive
2. An access db saved in google drive
3. An Excel file saved on google drive.

Thanks

Comment: A real cloud database such as FireBase might be a better solution. Google Sheet isn't really a database app.

Comment: Yes,  I know spreadsheets aren't the best option.  But, we have restrictions on what we can use to store data.  Google docs/drive is about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you, by any chance, tried using Google Apps Script for this.

Here's a simple tutorial:

https://zapier.com/blog/google-apps-script-tutorial/

Here's the complete API documentation (small examples included):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

I have configured fairly complex workflows by just using Google Apps Script with various Google Apps.